# Learning Distributions: What is the best way for a neural network to predict continuous output distributions from continuous input distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, neural-networks

Consider the situation, where one starts with a set of $n$ probability distributions $\{ P_{n}^{\rm in}\}$.  Each probability distribution $P_{n}^{\rm in}$ characterizes the distribution of some observable. For example, $P_{n}^{\rm in}$ could characterize how the internal energy of a gas of type $n$ is distributed. By that I mean, $P_{n}^{\rm in}(E_{\rm int})dE_{\rm int}$ gives you the probability of finding the gas $n$ to have an internal energy in the interval $[E_{\rm int},E_{\rm int}+dE_{\rm int}]$.

After mixing all $n$ different gases - a process which is highly complex to model - the system of mixed gas eventually converges to a new internal energy distributions $\{ P_{n}^{\rm out}\}$. So $P_{n}^{\rm out}$ characterizes the internal energy distribution of the gas of type $n$ after mixing.

Given a set of input distributions $P_{n}^{\rm in}$ one can obtain the correct product distributions $\{ P_{n}^{\rm out}\}$ by running computationally expensive numerical simulations. The task is to design a neural network-based model which predicts all $n$ product distributions $\{ P_{n}^{\rm out}\}$ given the set of $n$ input distributions $\{ P_{n}^{\rm in} \}$. For training and validating our model, one has different sets of input and corresponding output distributions $\{ (P_{n}^{\rm in},P_{n}^{\rm out}) \}$ that were obtained by running numerical simulations. This is the training and validation data.

What is the best way to tackle this problem? The problem seems non-trivial to me due to the fact that the input and output distributions may be continuous - so simple encoding of the value of the probability distribution at each point will be extremely inefficient, i.e., result in a neural network with huge input and output dimension. So instead, what inputs and outputs could one use to represent these continuous distributions? Are there any good references on how to use a neural network to predict continuous distributions from continuous distributions, i.e., is this a known problem to which there are already good solutions available?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by having "$n$ probability distributions"? How do you predict distributions from distributions? Those are distributions of what exactly? What is your data?

Comment: @Tim I just edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: But what are $P_n^{in}$ and $P_n^{out}?$

Comment: @Dave As I stated. They could, for example, be internal energy distributions. So $P_{n}$ would dictate how the internal energy of the gas is distributed: $P_{n}(E_{\rm int})dE_{\rm int}$ gives you the probability of finding the gas $n$ to have an internal energy in the interval $[E_{\rm int},E_{\rm int}+ dE_{\rm int}]$

Comment: Could you give example? What are those "probability distributions"?

Comment: @Tim I tried to further specify what I mean by internal energy distribution. This is simply an example.

Comment: `encoding of the value of the probability distribution at each point will be extremely inefficient, i.e., result in a neural network with huge input and output dimension.` Why? The probability distribution is encoded in the samples from that distribution which are rows, not columns, therefore it doesn't have a direct effect on the size of the neural network. Normally you have access to observations and the distribution is unknown and you are feeding these samples to NN. If you know the distribution, you can do the same by sampling from it. n distributions would result in n input features.